# onTap in GestureDetector is taking a value less, but Text is taking correct, both used in the same loop

Tags: flutter, loops, for-loop

In the following code, `Text(subjects[address])` is printing the correct value, but `GestureDetector( onTap:` is taking the same value for the whole `Row`, and incrementing the values of `subject` and `address` directly by 2 and 6 respectively, at exit from inner loop,

```
Column(
  children: [
    for (int i = 0, address = 0, subject = 0; i < 3; i++)
      Row(
        children: [
          for (int j = 0; j < 2; address += 3, subject++, j++)
            GestureDetector(
              child: Text(subjects[address]),
              onTap: () {.........},
            ),
        ],
      ),
  ],
),
```

the code prints:
[image],

so when i tap 'Second', `onTap` should execute the code of 'Second', which is `subject`('1' at Second), but it is taking '2', for both First and Second, and '4' for Third, and Fourth, and '6' for Fifth and Sixth,
and as `subject` is being incremented by 2, `address` is being incremented by 6,

Thanking you...

Comment: hello. please simply your problem. remove SubjectPage and replace print statement. and add actual and expected results. thanks.

Comment: the code prints what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Nearest Solution

[`GridView.count`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.count.html), with `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`, and `shrinkWrap: true`, and `crossAxisCount: 2`.

### Reason (behind code failure)

The correct (intended) behavior is shown by the outer loop ( inside `Column( children: [..],),`) as given in the official [language-tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#for-loops),
While the behavior shown by the inner loop ( inside `Row( children: [..],),`, is incorrect and wrong, possibly a bug,

### Official Quotation

Code:

```
var callbacks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  callbacks.add(() => print(i));
}
callbacks.forEach((c) => c());
```

Correct (intended) Output:

```
0
1
2
```

Incorrect (wrong) Output:

```
2
2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

While rendering the UI, it takes the current value of "subject" variable, so the UI part is correct.

OnTap does not work correctly because the value of subject variables gets changed after each iteration in the for loop, so when the ontap is called it just takes the last value of "subject" variable which is the 2,4,6 that you get for each ROW.

**Solution**:

1. Hard Code: If you are sure there are only 6 buttons on the screen then you could just hard code it.
2. Use ListView Builder: If the for loops condition is not constant then better use listview.builder (for row) within another listview.builder (for column).

The solution I have given is very short and abstract. Do comment if you need further explanation.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the case, actually, the actual insight which helped me solve this problem was a comment, which is now deleted, i must have quoted it as the answer, it was something like"dart uses a different approach to loops", maybe specifically the for-loops, they had also linked a official ```https://dart.dev/``` document, maybe the "Language Tour", or "Effective Dart", or something else...

Comment: oh cool okay will check it

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#for-loops